# Excessively verbose and cryptic comparisons in Java

Tags: java, programming-languages, readability, operators

I don't know if this is the right place to ask more of a "philosophical" question.
The more I code in Java, the more I have to bear with `Comparable<T>`. And the more I bear with this interface, the more my code gets verbose, maybe also cryptic. I'll take my last occurrence of the problem as an example:

```
list.get(j).compareTo(current) <= 0
```

The more i write lines such that, the more it makes this question pop in my mind: isn't this the time to introduce, even if only in more specific cases such as the `Comparable` interface, a sort of operator overloading in Java? Is it really so dangerous for programmers to write `list.get(j) <= current` instead of using these at-first-glance-cryptic return values of `compareTo`?
Is it my lack of experience that makes me think this, is there a more specific reason I'm not seeing?
And, more important thing, is there a way to improve readability for instructions like that?

Comment: I think you may be using things differently than intended - these are for ordering collections.  You may want to elaborate on your use case.   Anyway, you may want to look at Comparators which take two arguments.

Comment: If the type of the list elements is known and fixed, just use `<=`

Answer (score 5):

The point of `compareTo()` was never to make individual comparisons easier. The point is to allow using *standard algorithms*, such as sorting or limiting, on *user-defined types*. If you find a line like your example too cryptic, you're free to define a utility `limit()` so you can say

```
if(!below_limit(current_item, LEGAL_LIMIT)) {
    continue;
}
```

In fact, that's what I would do.

As for allowing operator overloading: that ship has sailed. The common point that operator overloading would allow too cryptic code to be written by means of badly chosen operators is a red herring; countless millions of lines of code are just as cryptic by means of badly chosen method names! The more important reason today is that Java has a strong commitment to backwards compatibility, and allowing a fundamental restructuring to the base of the language is simply way too expensive to be realistic, independent of the fashions of the day.

Comment: I totally agree with you. So many lines of code are cryptic because of variable and method names! I didn't think much about Java's commitment to backwards compatibility, that's true. Happy to know that you agree with me about the ban of operator overloading from so many languages. As a more conclusive answer to people who blame operator overloading for obscure coding, we can always overload just the standard methods (such as [] for access in lists, or < > for comparisons).

Comment: There is a major advantage of not allowing overloading, namely that the semantics of the code you look at are well-defined.  If you allow overloading, things can have a different meaning without you knowing unless you understand the whole codebase.  Bad method names are at least only that.

Comment: That's why I added that proposal at the end of my previous comment! If they implemented just the symbol < as an alias to o1.compareTo(o.2) <= 0, there wouldn't be any misunderstanding nor wrong supposition, no contrast with the principle of least astonishment. What else can a person expect from "<"? You usually even write it like that in pseudo code. You are not subverting the meaning of the operator itself, you're just extending its use cases.

Comment: @ThomasHerondale But how would you figure out that `<` suddenly has an additional meaning?  Or you suggest a change to the Java language itself?

Comment: *"you're free to define a utility..."* - this approach really is the root of evil in programming today. The point of a decent programming language and library is that you don't have to keep writing everything from scratch in assembly language, and the next guy looking at your code doesn't have to keep learning about all the endless creations, scaffolding, and wheels-within-wheels you've hand-crafted just to do basic things. It's like asking who needs a dictionary, when you can just compose new words from the alphabet yourself.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm afraid I don't understand your last comment? Do you mean how, in a reader's perspective, or as the author of the code?

Comment: @Steve I don't think utilities are always a problem... With the right naming, and/or a good documentation/reference, you shouldn't need to look up at the code. IDEs are useful too in that sense.

Comment: @Steve, you don't need to learn what `below_limit(current_item, LEGAL_LIMIT)` means - it says it right there; that kind of expressiveness is the whole point of programming languages. (Although `<` is not a great example.) It's not writing things from scratch, it's communicating what the code does. The only question is do you trust the code. 50 lines of comfortably familiar code doesn't tell you what the code *is for*: you have to read it and figure out what was the overall intent. Unless there's a bug in there or something, spending effort on reestablishing that intent is just a waste of time.

Comment: And if you can't trust your code, well, that's a problem, change that - train yourself and/or your teammates to write trustworthy code, develop practices around that, and improve writing skills in general.

Comment: Readers perspective.  Where is this new functionality defined?  Where in the source tree is it to be found?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I suppose in the class implementing the Comparable interface. Why would you need, as a reader, to see the definition of the < operator though? It's just the most common way to express what we usually express in Java using compareTo()

Comment: @FilipMilovanović, the problem is that the method may broadly say what it does, but unless you've studied the method then you don't know *exactly* what it does. It's really just guesswork that `below_limit` performs a simple comparison, and not some other complicated logic. And you can't have studied the method before you encounter it, because it's hand-crafted not standard to the language. And then the burden is put on the programmer to name things in an easy and systematic way - and many programmers will fail at that, too, because they're not experienced language designers.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen "But how would you figure out that < suddenly has an additional meaning?" Isn't the essential question whether < already has a meaning in that context?  At a (very) high-level, < isn't a valid operator between objects now so adding that as an alias to `compareTo` should create no ambiguity.  In practical terms though, I tend to agree with Killian here: it's probably too late.  Retrofitting this into typing, overloading, and overriding in Java seems like a daunting challenge.

Comment: @JimmyJames So you suggest adding it to the language itself by default (like with plus) and not be specified by the programmer somewhere in the project?  It might, if you suggest it in a JEP to the Java architects.  I don't think they want it though.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen So if you've ever dug into Python, if you define a method on your class called `__lt__(self, other)` and/or `__gt__(self, other)`, that's what is called when you use < or >.  I think that's basically what was being discussed.

Comment: @JimmyJames Probably.  This is not uncommon, just not done in Java (except for plus to add strings).  I still think that the basic problem here is that OP is using comparators outside collections.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen "just not done in Java" For sure, I know.  I'm an OJD (original java developer.)  Well, I jumped on the bandwagon at version 1.2 anyway.  This is all the context of the discussion.